# Leaflet animated marker not displaying the latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am using this code it shows the message in a popup when I remove the `e.latlng.lat and + e.latlng.lng`

```
var myMovingMarker = L.Marker.movingMarker([
  [23.59582641820334, 58.439605236053474],
  [21.5278654, 55.9196996]
], [100000], {
  icon: orangeIcon
}, {
  title: "MyPoint",
  alt: "The Big I",
  draggable: true
}, )

var popup = L.popup({
  keepInView: false,
  autoPan: false,
  closeButton: false,
  closeOnClick: true,
  maxWidth: 1000

}).setContent("Lat, Lon : " + e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng)

myMovingMarker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup()
```

Comment: Have you add marker to map `L.Marker.movingMarker().addTo(map)`

Comment: yes and it shows and display the popup when i write it like this                                   =>>> .setContent("Lat, Lon : " ) but when i ask for lat  lng the marker doent display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `e` is not defined. Additionally `setContent()` set a static content, this means when you add text with `setContent()` is will not updated, even if the marker latlng has changed.

You have to set the content every time the popup is opened:

```
myMovingMarker.on('popupopen',function(e){
    var markerLatLng = e.popup._source.getLatLng();
    e.popup.setContent("Lat, Lon : " + markerLatLng.lat + ", " + markerLatLng.lng)
  })
```

Another way would be to updated the content every time the marker is moved:

```
myMovingMarker.on('move',function(e){
    var markerLatLng = e.target.getLatLng();
    popup.setContent("Lat, Lon : " + markerLatLng.lat + ", " + markerLatLng.lng)
  })
```

PS: Both not tested, but should work